# function call with different semantics

Tags: c, function

Considering this code with 3 differents function call semantics:

```
void f(void){
   puts("OK");
}

int main(void){
   f();
  (*f)();
  (&f)();

  return 0;
}
```

The first is the standard way to call f,

the second is the semantic for dereferencing function pointers,

but in the third I'm applying the & operator to the function name and it seems to work fine.

What does in the second and third case happen?

Thanks.

Comment: The pointer to the function gets dereferenced for the call in the third.

Comment: For fun try `(**********f)();` as well

Comment: I' m asking in which case someone should use the second and the third call...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function calls are **always** performed via function pointers.  From C99 section 6.5.2.2:

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type pointer to function.

However, in almost all cases a function type decays to a function-pointer type.  From C99 section 6.3.2.1:

> Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with
>   type "function returning *type*" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to
>   function returning *type*".

So your three calls are evaluated thus:

```
(&f)();
(&(*(&f)))();
(&f)();
```

All are valid.  But obviously, the first one (`f()`) is the cleanest and easiest to read.

Comment: why not (&(&f)()) valid.When &f decays to function-pointer type?

Comment: @softy: `&f` is **already** a function-pointer type.  So `&&f` is a function-pointer-pointer type.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Only that `&f` is an r-value, so it cannot be the argument of another `&` unary operator.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you are using a function pointer. Function pointers are used to memorize a reference to a function, and be able to call it elsewhere in your call. They are typically used to implement callbacks.
So if you have store a pointer to a function you should use the first notation.

I thinkg the first and the third are equivalent.
In fact if you declare a function pointer you can initialize it both the following ways:

```
void AFunction();
void (*funcPtr)() = NULL;

funcPtr = AFunction; 
funcPtr = &AFunction;
```