# How to get c function Bytes and convert it into char

Tags: c

I looking a way to load function and cast it into a char  ;
I'd like to get bytes of it .

```
void myFunc();
int main()
{
   char myChar =(char)&myFunc; // stuff like that
   return 0;
}
void myFunc()
{
   printf("hi!");
}
```

I hava tried to dereference my adress pointer @user2482551:

here is my new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myFunc(){
    printf("hi");

}
int main(){
    unsigned int* c = (unsigned int*)(&myFunc);

    printf("%d\n",*c);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT : -443987883

Do you know what does it mean ?

Comment: what do you want `myChar` to be? a pointer to a function? or the string `"hi!"`?

Comment: @Pavel it has the aroma of a SMC (self-modifying code) attempt.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well any modern OS will probably end any 'SMC' attempt with a single 'segmentation fault' :)

Comment: No I'd like to get function "bytes" which are the RAM at the adress of `&myFunc`

Comment: This is so compiler, architecture, and OS dependent that it should not even be something you ask about on stack overflow.

Comment: @user2777579 If you want to do that use Candy man's answer. Then you dereference myChar and that will be the byte. It will probably be meaningless since instructions are not going to be 8 bits anyway.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785815/why-dereferencing-the-main-function-does-not-show-memory-content/23787780#23787780, the answer(s) to that apply here also.

Comment: `myFunc` might not be in RAM

Comment: Ohhh right i missed that !!
I guess i have to find a function in kernel.dll to do that ?
(I am on windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get the address of myFunc and step bytewise through memory starting from that address when you type a key:

```
void myFunc();
int main()
{
   void* ptr = &myFunc; // stuff like that
   while(getchar() != -1) {
     printf("%d", *((char*)ptr++));
   }
   return 0;
}
void myFunc()
{
   printf("hi!");
}
```

Here's the output I get:

```
[gregor@localhost tmp]$ ./faddr

85
72
-119
-27
-65
-109
6
```

I wouldn't be able to tell if this is actually stepping through the machine code for the function ... Maybe you have a way to check this? E.g use something simpler like:

```
int myFunc() 
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "tell if this is actually stepping through the machine code " -- it does. Printing the result as unsigned hex shows `55 48 89 E5 30 C0 48 8D 0D 41 00 00 00 48 89 CF E8 09 00 00 00 5D C3 ..`, starting with a `push`. Stopped at `C3` because that's a `RET` instruction.

Comment: Note this isn't really portable, since you're not supposed to convert function pointers to `void *`, but if you're trying to get at machine code then you're probably not going to care.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you want

```
char* myChar =(char*)&myFunc; // stuff like that
```

You cannot convert an address to a `char`, but of course you can convert it to a pointer-to-char `char*`.

Also, define the function above main, or if not, declare its prototype `void myFunc();` above main. Otherwise `main()` does not "see" it and you get a compile time error.

Comment: Yes Sorry for the msitake

Comment: of course, myChar will only contain address of the function, nut the byte representation of the complete function.

Comment: @CandyMan not sure I get it... what do you mean by the "byte representation of the function"? The actual values of the physical memory addresses where `f` is stored? Like a memory dump?

Comment: I just want to point out to the OP, since the title was 'get C function bytes' that myChar will not contain the machine code for 'printf("hi");'

Comment: Yes didn't wrote that (  for prototype ) but when  casting to char* and printing it, i just get things like that :  `Ê*ëÕHâý Hì`

Comment: @CandyMan completely agree! I don't know actually of any simple way of getting the machine code, as I do not know how to get the "size" of the function.

Comment: @CandyMan agreed. And depending on the platform, it may not even contain the correct *code* address of the function in the first place.

Comment: @user2777579 you shouldn't "print" the `char*`, it is a pointer pointing to some stuff in the memory, not a `C`-like string. It will print until if finds a `\0` in the memory.

Comment: @WhozCraig, why wouldn't `char* myChar` contain the correct code address? At least up to the operating system level physical mapping?

Comment: @vsoftco I guess one could get the machine code with the appropriate offset (assuming that the code is laid sequentially in the memory). Never really tried that, because there is really no reason for doing that.

Comment: @CandyMan it likely will be sequential. The address of the function will likely be the address of the first instruction in the function. Also, the instructions will likely not be 8 bit, so multiple chars would span a single instruction.

Comment: @vsoftco because function pointers and data pointers are not necessarily the same size. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696918/c-cast-void-pointer-to-function-pointer/13697654#13697654).

Comment: "you can convert it to a pointer-to-char" - not in standard C, although it is a common extension

Comment: @CandyMan this approach would be usable to retrieve the machine code (if the compiler allows the conversion of function pointer to char pointer).